# Geolocalization, reverse geocoder, callbacks and object deallocation

Tags: iphone, reverse-geocoding, memory-management

In my app, I get the user location and do the reverse geocoder. At the same time the user can write a note.
Sometimes, when I debug and run my app, I obtain this msg:

```
*** -[MyViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x61a6920
```

I don't succeed in resolving this, but I noted that disabling the geolocalization the problem doens't appear (at least until now). 
So I thought that, when the geolocalization in on, the reverse geocoder (a separate thread) can return when the controller has been already deallocated.
Could it be possible? If the case, how is it possible avoid it?

Thanks,

Fran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely possible (in fact, a fairly common error) for the delegate for an asynchronous process like reverse geocoding to get dealloc'ed out from under that process. When that happens, the (in this case) geocoder will happily call its delegate method on the deallocated delegate object, exactly like you're seeing.

That's why `MKReverseGeocoder` has a `-cancel` method. You want to call that on `-(void)dealloc` in the class you're using as a geocoder delegate. And maybe also set your geocoder's delegate to `nil`.

That might very likely mean that you need to add a named/synthesized property to that class to keep a handle to the geocoder around. So that you HAVE it to say "cancel" TO in your dealloc method.